# Apply policy to a path in asp.net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

In my asp.net-core application I use policies (e.g. "IsAdmin") to secure certain parts of the application.

I have an admin area located at the path /admin. I would like require a policy for every controller/page located under this path instead of decorating every controller with the [Autorization] attribute.

Is there a way to set this up in startup.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK , no such configuration enable path filter for policy . As a workaround , you can create a base controller definition for that area that overrides Controller, and add the security require to this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireElevatedRights")]
public abstract class AdminController : Controller { }
```

Then you just have to ensure each controller in the area overrides AdminController instead of Controller:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class HomeController : AdminController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Another solution is applying a global authorization requirement :

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{

    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("AtLeast21"));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
});

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumAgeHandler>();
```

In handle you should check whether the area is the specfic one :

```
IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;

public MinimumAgeHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,                                                       MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
{
    var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
    var descriptor = mvcContext?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
    if (!("Admin".Equals(descriptor.RouteValues["area"])))
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    ...........
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The key to my problem was solved by these lines:

services.AddMvc(config =>
{

    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("AtLeast21"));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

In the RequirementsHandler I can now check the request path and fullfill the requirement based on user and path.